# Gradle Multi-Project Build is Looking Like a Dry Run

Tags: java, spring, gradle, cross-platform

So I was given this legacy project which is built with Gradle. This project builds perfectly on linux machines with a simple `./gradlew clean build`. However in my windows machine, if I execute the same command the project builts successfully but it is looking like it was a dry run of the build.
I say this because in linux the build takes me around 1 hour while in windows it takes only 50 seconds.

Additionally, I know for a fact that the build on windows is not even running the integration tests nor compiling the java, since some of the imports are even failing.

What makes this most strange is that it works on linux and not on windows.
Please advise.

I will attach the `build.gradle` maybe it will be useful:

```
subprojects {

  apply plugin: "java"
  apply plugin: "idea"
  apply plugin: 'org.springframework.boot'
  apply plugin: 'org.junit.platform.gradle.plugin'
  apply from: "${rootProject.projectDir}/gradle/check/check.gradle"
  bootRepackage.enabled = false

  repositories {
    mavenCentral()
    maven { url 'https://jitpack.io' }
  }

  ext {
    buildTag = project.hasProperty('buildTag') ? "-${buildTag}" : ""
    assertjVersion = "3.6.2"
    junitVersion = "5.3.1"
    junitPlatformVersion = "1.3.1"
    jitPackVersion = "1.0.0"
    mockitoVersion = "2.+"
    commonsLang3Version = "3.5"
    commonsBeanUtilsVersion = "1.9.3"
    mssqlJdbcVersion = "6.1.0.jre8"
    flywayVersion = "4.1.2"
    swaggerVersion = "2.7.0"
    commonsIOVersion = "2.5"
    awaitilityVersion = "3.0.0"
    cyberSourceClientVersion = "6.2.4"
    sshdVersion = "1.6.0"
    springSftpVersion = "4.3.10.RELEASE"
    jacksonVersion = "2.8.6"
    javaxVersion = "3.1.0"
    httpclientVersion = "4.5.2"
    apiGuardianVersion = "1.0.0"
  }

  version = "1.1.6${buildTag}"

  configurations {
    compile.exclude module: "spring-boot-starter-tomcat"
  }

  compileJava {
    sourceCompatibility = 1.8
    targetCompatibility = 1.8
  }

  dependencies {
    compile "org.apache.commons:commons-lang3:${commonsLang3Version}"

    testCompile "org.assertj:assertj-core:${assertjVersion}"
  }
}

task wrapper(type: Wrapper) {
  gradleVersion = '3.4.1'
}

buildscript {
  repositories {
    mavenCentral()
    jcenter()
  }
  dependencies {
    classpath("org.springframework.boot:spring-boot-gradle-plugin:1.5.1.RELEASE")
    classpath('org.junit.platform:junit-platform-gradle-plugin:1.0.0-M4')
  }
}
```

EDIT: After running with `./gradlew clean build --info` I can see most of the tasks have `NO-SOURCE` or `UP-TO-DATE` next to them which does not happen on Linux

Comment: I don't see anything wrong with the build file. If you run with the `-i` parameter, you should see if the individual tasks are executed or are skipped due to them being up-to-date, cached or disabled. Maybe that can help shed some light on the situation.

Comment: Thank you, that gave me one more hint. Most of the tasks have next to them UP-TO-DATE or NO-SOURCE but in Linux it does not appear. Any idea?

Comment: Both those states indicates that Gradle couldn't find any source code to compile. By default, Java source code is in `src/main/java` but my guess is that your project somehow reconfigures that folder, perhaps using environment properties or Unix style paths in a way that doesn't work on Windows. Could you check the Gradle build file in the individual subprojects to see if they do something funky like that?

Comment: Hello Bjorn, I found multiple entries like this ```srcDir file('src/integration-test/resources')``` is this ```file``` method OS dependent, or maybe on windows this path can not get resolved? Thank you